# Laravel, what is better normal authentication or Passport?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

I am developing a web app and I am very curious about Passport, perhaps I don't quite understand if its basically better for authenticating using Oauth2 as a open standard than regular Laravel authentication since my app is not authenticating through another server?

Can you please advise? Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport is more geared towards APIs than web apps so you are better off using the standard authentication method in Laravel.

Even on Laravel's Passport page the title is "API Authentication (Passport)": https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

If you would like to learn more about what an API is and its uses:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew it was for APIs but Ive seen sites using OAuth for a non-API purpose within their site. My question was related if it was just a better practice.