# How to Auth::check() user on Laravel with API calls

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, oauth

I'm using VueJS in my front-end, so I have this API call somewhere in the front-end code:

```
let products = axios.get('api/products');
```

And then in the **routes/api.php**:-

```
Routes::get('products', 'ProductsController@index');
```

in the **ProductsController**'s index method:

```
public function index () {

    if ( Auth::check() ) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return $user->products;
    }
    // return 'You don't have any products right now!';
}
```

The **index** method will always return null even if the user is logged-in!

So how to authenticate the users in this case while using the API calls?

Comment: are you sending the api token in http request ? If you are sending the api token then you can add `auth:api` middleware to your route `Routes::get('products', 'ProductsController@index')->middleware('auth:api');`

Comment: No, I'm not sending the api token, I don't know in which part should I send it.

Comment: check this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport for api authenticate

Comment: Yes, I have seen **Laravel's Passport** library before, but I don't think it's necessary for such a simple authentication

Comment: Laravel passport has simple authentication too, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#personal-access-tokens

Comment: did you checked `dd($user->products);` from your browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sending auth token because when we write the API we need to deal with auth token and not with Auth::check().
You need to send auth token with user id at the time of api call and verify that details to proceed.

Comment: Yes, in the browser console, if I write **window.Laravel** I get this results: 
    {csrfToken: "wtkWtQAm4Yn04gT7IirAZKTk9g7aRpzuqaxUEJKC", userId: "0ce16782-1582-46f9-9a42-0d2280d7a1e6"}

Comment: Then you dont need to check  Auth::check(), you can verify that user by token and userdId

Comment: You can get that user by authenticating user with userId and token

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but I was thinking about some extra back-end verification..

Comment: In the API we need to use token to verify the User

Comment: Okay, so how is this method compared to **Laravel's Passport** https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport , I mean which one is more appropriate in this case ?

Comment: It has already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989191/laravel-what-is-better-normal-authentication-or-passport

Answer (score 1):

You can check user Auth of API calls by this:

At first add this use code in your Class:

```
use Auth;
```

Then add this code in your function:

```
    if (Auth::guard('api')->check())
    {
        logger(Auth::guard('api')->user()); // to get user

    }else{
        logger("User not authorized");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the data via json and decode them in your frontend again. Maybe this helps?

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you're sending the CSRF token, somewhere in your `bootstrap.js` file, you should have something like this. Also make sure you have the `csrf` token somewhere in the meta tag

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

    if (token) {
        window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': Laravel.csrfToken,
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        };
    } else {
        console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
    }
```

Comment: The csrfToken is already bound to the **window.Laravel.csrfToken** and it's also added as meta tag in the blade view, This doesn't help